# Al cambiar un valor de un diccionario común en Python, se modifica el valor en todos los diccionarios que lo usen

Tags: python, diccionarios

En resumen, yo tengo un diccionario que contiene informacion común. Por ejemplo:

```
dictG = {'KeyG1': 'Hola', 'KeyG2': 'Adios'}
```

Ahora este diccionario lo uso en otros diccionarios:

```
dict1 = {'Key1': dictG, 'Key2': dictG}
dict2 = {'Key3': dictG, 'Key4': dictG}
```

Todo esto se encuentra dentro de un mapa. Ahora, cuando intento modificar el valor de una clave concreta, esta se cambia en el mapa entero. Código de ejemplo:

```
map['Key2']['KeyG1'] = 'Prueba'
```

Y el resultado que obtengo es:

```
ChainMap({'Key1': {'KeyG1': 'Prueba', 'KeyG2': 'Adios'},
'Key2': {'KeyG1': 'Prueba', 'KeyG2': 'Adios'},
'Key3': {'KeyG1': 'Prueba', 'KeyG2': 'Adios'},
'Key4': {'KeyG1': 'Prueba', 'KeyG2': 'Adios'}})
```

Cuando lo que espero es:

```
ChainMap({'Key1': {'KeyG1': 'Hola', 'KeyG2': 'Adios'},
'Key2': {'KeyG1': 'Prueba', 'KeyG2': 'Adios'},
'Key3': {'KeyG1': 'Hola', 'KeyG2': 'Adios'},
'Key4': {'KeyG1': 'Hola', 'KeyG2': 'Adios'}})
```

Entonces no sé por qué ocurre.

Answer (score 4):

Has creado un objeto:

```
dictG = {'KeyG1': 'Hola', 'KeyG2': 'Adios'}
```

cuando lo asignas a otros objetos:

```
a = dictG
b = dictG
```

tanto `a`, `b` quedan referenciando ("apuntando") al objeto original; **no** se sacan copia!!!

Lo puedes comprobar preguntando por el `id` de cada uno:

```
>>> id(dictG), id(a), id(b)
(140019319438080, 140019319438080, 140019319438080)
```

Las tres variables (`dictG, a, b`) apuntan al mismo objeto en memoria.

Por tanto, si cambio el contenido de cualquiera de los tres, los otros verán reflejado el cambio:

```
>>>a["otro"] = "nuevo valor"
>>>id(dictG), id(a), id(b)
(140019319438080, 140019319438080, 140019319438080)
b
{'KeyG1': 'Hola', 'KeyG2': 'Adios', 'otro': 'nuevo valor'}
```

#### Solución

Si quieres una **copia** del objeto, usas el método `copy`.

Aquí creamos dos copias de `dictG` y luego las modificamos:

```
>>>dictG = {'KeyG1': 'Hola', 'KeyG2': 'Adios'}
>>>a=dictG.copy()
>>>b=dictG.copy()
>>>a["ind_a"] = "a"
>>>b["ind_b"] = "b"
```

El resultado son tres objetos distintos:

```
>>>id(dictG), id(a), id(b)
(140019293780544, 140019293777984, 140019319564800)
```

cada uno con sus propios valores:

```
>>>dictG, a, b
({'KeyG1': 'Hola', 'KeyG2': 'Adios'}, {'KeyG1': 'Hola', 'KeyG2': 'Adios', 'ind_a': 'a'}, {'KeyG1': 'Hola', 'KeyG2': 'Adios', 'ind_b': 'b'})
```

Obs: Existe el método `deepcopy`, que copia recursivamente el contenido del objeto.